# JavaScript onclick not firing on <li> tag in JSP

Tags: javascript, function, jsp, html-lists

I have this little JavaScript function:

```
function exeForm(option, pageToLoad, optionId) {

    var frm = document.getElementById("frmSessionForm");
    var frmOpt = document.getElementById("frmSessionOption");
    var frmOptId = document.getElementById("frmSessionOptionId");

    frm.action = pageToLoad;
    frmOpt.value = option;
    frmOptId.value = optionId;

    frm.submit();
}
```

The function should be called whenever I click the link. But that won't happen. Here's my HTML code:

```
<li><a href="#">Card</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#foo" onclick="exeForm(0,'CardManage.jsp',0);"></a>Search</li>
        <li><a href="#foo" onclick="exeForm(1,'CardManage.jsp',0);"></a>Confirm</li>
        <li><a href="#foo" onclick="exeForm(2,'CardManage.jsp',0);"></a>New</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
function exeForm(option, pageToLoad, optionId) {

alert("Inside function");
    var frm = document.getElementById("frmSessionForm");
    var frmOpt = document.getElementById("frmSessionOption");
    var frmOptId = document.getElementById("frmSessionOptionId");

    frm.action = pageToLoad;
    frmOpt.value = option;
    frmOptId.value = optionId;

    frm.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
    <body>

        <li><a href="#">Card</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#foo" onclick="exeForm(0,'CardManage.jsp',0);">Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="#foo" onclick="exeForm(1,'CardManage.jsp',0);">Confirm</a></li>
        <li><a href="#foo" onclick="exeForm(2,'CardManage.jsp',0);">New</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this too. I only get the alert. Could it by chance be a Mozilla issue?

Comment: actually your function gets  null on line  "var frm = document.getElementById("frmSessionForm");" beacuse it cannot find any element with id "frmSessionForm". So first put proper id's of element to work above code properly..

Comment: Thanks man, I set form name="frmSessionForm", which was my mistake. I should have set form id="...". Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Just place the text inside  element like

```
   <a href="#foo" onclick="exeForm(0,'CardManage.jsp',0);">Search</a>
```